# Getting layer information + sending it via socket io to a client

Tags: qgis, python, layers, qgis-2

I am new to QGIS and I was wondering if there was a way to get the information from a layer (its name for example), and to send it to a client via a python-socket.io server?

A this very moment I have a very simple python-socket.io server and an angular client, all I am looking to do at the moment is just a simple communication where a layer name is sent from server to client.

I have been looking around the QGIS Dev Cookbook but I haven't been able to find the proper info regarding this at all.

Comment: Did you find a solution?